# Pre-filled message for the user in Facebook share dialog.

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-plugins

I came across to know that fb has removed pre-filling message parameter. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

> Pre-fill the user message parameter with any content the user didn't
>   enter themselves, even if they can edit or delete that content before
>   sharing. This applies to posts, comments, photo captions, and photo
>   album captions.

I am using "SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin" and want to post user's score at his fb-wall. Is there any workaround so that I can prefill the share dialog description with user's score. Secondly the web link also not working it only allowing picture to post.

Comment: if you use default share intent of android than you can't prefill message. you have to register your app on  https://developers.facebook.com/ than share.

Answer (score 0):

use this code. but you have to register your application on https://developers.facebook.com/. Get AppId and use it.

```html
CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginManager manager;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
  setContentView(R.layout.Your_layout);
  callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  //call method for sharing post
  FaceBookSharing();
}

public void FaceBookSharing() {
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
 manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
 manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

 manager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
  new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    PostImage();
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancel() {
    System.out.println("onCancel");
   }

   @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
    System.out.println("onError");
   }
 });
}
private void PostImage() {
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.ic_launcher);

 SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image)
    .setCaption("Hey this is Demo post!")
    .build();

 SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(
    photo).build();

 ShareApi.share(content, null);
 Toast.makeText(this, "Succsesfully posted on your wall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
 .show(); 
}
```

Comment: SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image)
    .setCaption("Hey this is Demo post!")
    .build();      here add your text in caption.

Comment: But you are setting the "Caption" param and you have to register your app get auth-token from the user then you are able to post on behalf of that user. But I was asking share-dialog that don't require any permissions, and unfortunately FB has removed the custom message param.